# Showing ‘fetching’ for user permission in plist file inside the cocoa app bundle

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, permissions, plist

In my cocoa application, i am using one plist file(preference.plist) to save the preference inside the app bundle. I am using package maker to pack my app(Business requirement). For that, i will build my app and export as a Developer ID-Signed application.  If i check the sharing and permission info of my app, it will show like this

[image]

In my local system, i can write on this preference.plist file with this user permission.  If i install the same in my client machine, it shows fetching for all the time.

[image]

In this case, i can't  write in preference.plist file. Don’t know why this strange behaviour occurs for my app. Hope the above scenes will explain my problem. Please provide the solution to accomplish this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store writable files in your app bundle, especially if you then intend to sign the bundle.

If you cannot store your preferences in your apps user defaults then your app should create a directory to hold its files, usually named after its bundle ID, in user or system Application Support directory - you can find its URL using `URLsForDirectory` requesting `NSApplictionSupportDirectory`.

Doing the above should solve your permissions problem (and work correctly if sandboxed).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i got a reference from this [link](http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_changing_file_owner_chown)

When copying a file between one system and another, occasionally both the permissions and owner for the files will be incorrect. You may need to change the owner of the file because the file is unable to be edited by the user due to permissions issues.

We’ll rely on the “chown” command to change the owner of a specified group of files, right from the command line.

**chown command:**

```
sudo chown -Rv $USER /Applications/TEST.app
```

This command works fine. Now in permission area, its not showing "fetching". I have included this command in package maker post script.